# How to resize the picture taken on Android?

Tags: android

I want to send a picture I took to server with multipart/form-data.

Of course, all the process goes very well.

I get the absolute path of the picture on onActivityResult. I sent it to AsyncTask class to change it into File object. Then, I use FileInputStream to send the picture to server.

Here's my code for sending picture.

MainActivity:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA){
        // uri of selected picture
        imageUri = data.getData();


        // path of selected picture
        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();
        absolutePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));

        Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(image);
    }
}
```

Asynctask class: 
absolutePath is in params[7]

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream ;
        wr.writeBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        wr.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file1[]\"; " +
                "filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n");
        wr.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(params[7]);
```

When I send the picture, I just send it without resizing.
It takes too much time and data to finish sending. 
I want to make the picture smaller when sending to server.
that is, with absolute Path, I want to make smaller picture that can be turned into File object.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your imageFile as Uri variable and then resize your image according to your desired width and height to be compressed.

```
     Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(fileUri));
     Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, false);
     FileOutputStream fOut;

     try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileUri);
            out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            b.recycle();
            out.recycle();
            Log.i("Compressing file", String.valueOf(uriFile));
      } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ErrInCompressingPicture",""  + e);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the picture you got before you send to server!

one solution is set inSampleSize directly:

```
  public static Bitmap getImage(String imgPath){
      BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inSampleSize=2;
      try {
          b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
      } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return b;
 }
```

the other solution is set width and height of you want:

```
public static Bitmap getSmallBitmap(String imgPath,int reWidth,int reHeight) {
     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
     int width = options.outWidth;
     int height = options.outHeight;
     int inSampleSize=0;
     if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
         final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
         final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
         inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
     options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
     return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
  }
```